# ngSmoothScroll angular directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using the following directive https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSmoothScroll to make stuff in this project smoothly scroll to the selected element.

Here's my code:

```
...
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <script src="bower_components/ngSmoothScroll/dist/angular-smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/initcontroller.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
        <script src="scripts/libs/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/libs/angular-materialize.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

That's where the script is included `(~/angular-smooth-scroll.min.js)` and inside my `app.js` file I have:

```
angular
  .module('sccateringApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.materialize',
    'smoothScroll'
  ])
```

`'smoothScroll'` being the actual dependency inclusion to the project. Following the instructions inside the link given at the beginning of this post this is what I do inside my view:

```
<li><a href="#" scroll-to="service-info" container-id="service-info">Contáctame</a></li>
...

<section class="service-info" id="service-info">
<h1 class="sofia-font">Detalles de Servicio</h1>
...
```

However, there is no smooth scroll happening and also, there are no warnings/errors given by either the console or jslint on my `grunt serve` task.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I'm VERY new to angular and I'm still trying to find my way through it.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing too. Do you have any luck?

Comment: Your scroll-to and container-id have the same element id, so it makes sense that no scroll will occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but it may be because you are using the container-id on a link and not a non-anchor tag. I'm using this to scroll to an element in my footer. My code is:

```
//the anchor link in my nav
 <a href="#" scroll-to="footer" duration="2500">Click Me</a>
 ...

//the element I want to scroll to
 <div id="footer"></div>
 ...
```

The minified version wasn't working for me so my scripts go as follows:

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script src="/bower_components/ngSmoothScroll/lib/angular-smooth-scroll.js"></script>

<script src="/js/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.controller.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.service.js"></script>
```

And for the module:

```
angular
   .module('glasser', [
      'ngMaterial',
      'ngSanitize',
      'smoothScroll'
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me either, try [Angular-Scroll](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll) instead. It has a live demo to test in your browser first.

It also has a 'spy' directive so you can add classes to elements that are in view.